# Proving using complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

How do i prove this:
I tried proving this all day long
\begin{eqnarray*} 
1 + 2 \cos(x) + 2 \cos(2x) + \cdots + 2 \cos(nx) = \frac{\sin((2n+1)/2)x}{\sin(x/2)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
It should be by using complex numbers.
Thanks

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you relate $\cos(x)$ to complex numbers?

Comment: Hint: $\cos(x) =Re(e^{ix})$ ...

Comment: knew that and after a lot of algebra couldnt get to correct expression..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formulæ are standard  and obtained using the complex exponential:
\begin{align}
1+\cos x+\cos 2x+\dots+\cos nx&=\frac{\sin\cfrac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\dfrac x2}\,\cos \frac {nx}2\\[1ex]%
\sin x+\sin 2x+\dots+\sin nx&=\frac{\sin\cfrac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\dfrac x2}\,\sin \frac {nx}2
\end{align}
Using the first formula, we obtain:
\begin{align}
1+2\cos x&+2\cos 2x+\dots+2\cos nx=2\frac{\sin\cfrac{(n+1)x}{2}}{\sin\dfrac x2}\,\cos \frac {nx}2-1 \\[1ex]
&=\frac{2\sin\cfrac{(n+1)x}{2}\cos \dfrac {nx}2-\sin\dfrac x2}{\sin\dfrac x2}=\frac{\sin\cfrac{(2n+1)x}{2}+\sin \dfrac {x}2-\sin\dfrac x2}{\sin\dfrac x2},
\end{align}
using in the last step the *linearisation formula*:
$$2\sin a \cos b=\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b).$$

Comment: where did u get the first equation from?

Comment: I learnt it in high school. The two left-hand sides are the real and imaginary parts of the partial sum  of the geometric $\sum_{k=0}^n \mathrm e^{ikx}$.